# Android Trying to display a welcome fragment when app starts, but not after

Tags: java, android, fragment

I've been looking for a way to have the blank detail side of my fragment layout host a welcome screen (or something - login perhaps) on start up. Afterwards, when a user presses one of the left side menu items, I'd like to eliminate the fragment for the remainder of the program run. I don't want to add it to the backstack, as that messes up my configuration changes. I've considered using shared prefs to host a boolean about whether the fragment has been displayed. The only concern with this method is where to safely reset the boolean value for the next run of the app. I'm of the impression that there's no gaurantee that the onStop, onDetach etc. will definitely get called upon closing of the app, so if the app got closed in the wrong state, it would be rendered useless ( the first fragment wouldn't display - crash )
Anyone have any ideas on how I could implement a filler for the right side of the app upon startup?

I've been trying to add something to the onCreate of my main activity thus far with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution to creating a welcome or login screen which will display both fragments and activities from the main activity. Seems to be working fine as tested.

```
private boolean welcomeShown;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);

        if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) { 
            mTwoPane = true;
            ((MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.item_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
                    welcomeShown = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("displayed");
        }

        if(!welcomeShown){

            if (mTwoPane){
                WelcomeFragment welcomeFragment = new WelcomeFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.item_detail_container, welcomeFragment)
                        .commit();
            }
            else{

                Intent welcomeIntent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(welcomeIntent);
                welcomeShown = true;
            }
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("displayed", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fragment can be part of its own Activity, you can use the `android:noHistory="true"` attribute to keep the Activity off of the backstack.  If your user tries to navigate backwards, it'll hit the bottom of the backstack twice before exiting your application.

If you can't split your fragment into its own activity, `noHistory` may not work -- I can't say as I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks, I just looked into that a bit, and don't think it'll work for my situation since it seems to be an activity only setting, but it may work should I decide to use the same fragment/activity in portrait mode.